# How to map multiple images in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, create-react-app

I'm trying to map multiple images in ReactJS.
Here is the code:

```
{Object.entries(images).map((image, index) => {
     <img src={image[1].default} width="640" height="480" id={'image' + index} alt={'image' + index} />
})}
```

The problem is that in the browser I can't see any image, if I add manually a location from the second image the image is showing.
e.g: `<img src="/static/media/img.bmp" width="640" height="480" id={'image' + 1} alt={'image' + 2} />`

Webstorm IDE show this error: `Expression statement is not assignment or call`

Comment: Can you open the image in the browser using this URL?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning any image from `map`.

Try this:

```js
{Object.entries(images).map((image, index) => 
     <img src={image[1].default} width="640" height="480" id={'image' + index} alt={'image' + index} />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically `require` the image from `webpack`

```
{Object.entries(images).map((image, index) => 
     <img src={require(image[1].default)} width="640" height="480" id={'image' + index} alt={'image' + index} />
)}
```